# Can't get raw_input to return a number

Tags: python, string, user-input, python-2.x

```
print "How old are you?",
age = raw_input()
print "How tall are you in inches?",
height = raw_input()
print "How much do you weigh in pounds",
weight = raw_input()

print "So, you are %r years old, %r inches tall, and %d kilograms." % (
age, height, weight / 2.2)
```

So I am new to code and this is my code. When I use terminal to compile it, I get this:

```
How old are you? 1
How tall are you in inches? 1
How much do you weigh in pounds 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ex11.py", line 9, in <module>
   age, height, weight / 2.2) 
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'float'
```

Can someone please explain to me what I did wrong?

Comment: The raw input is always a string; you have to convert it or cast it to a numeric type before you can divide by 2.2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`raw_input`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) always returns a string object.  You need to explicitly convert this into a number object if you plan to use it as such (perform mathematical operations on it):

```
weight = int(raw_input())

#or

weight = float(raw_input())
```

Use [`int`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int) if the number will always be an integer.  Otherwise, use [`float`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#float) if the input can have a decimal part such as `10.1`.

Comment: casting to float is probably the safer approach, what if somebody weights 42.42 pounds and puts that in?

Answer (score 1):

`raw_input()` returns a `string`. You will need to cast your `weight` to float:

```
weight = float(weight)
```

Or in one line:

```
weight = float(raw_input())
```